# Use specific JavaScript code when on iOS and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have two `JavaScript` snippets. One of them works well on all browsers except `Google Chrome` on `iOS` and the other snippet works really well for `Google Chrome` on `iOS`.

I would like to use a specific `JavaScript` code when a user visits my site with `Google Chrome` on `iOS` but use a different `JavaScript` code for every other browser.

Comment: Have you tried `google.com`?

Comment: Share your code and be more specific.

There are ways to check what browser is being used. You need to provide a more explicit question for proper recommendations to be made.

Comment: @4DAWIN did my answer help?

Comment: still trying to make it work. Have not worked yet

Comment: please consider accepting answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [ua-parser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js)

```
var parser = new UAParser();
if(parser.getBrowser().name === "Chrome" && parser.getOS().name === "iOS") {
  //....
}
```